# How do I click Javascript alert using Watir-webdriver while automating on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to close the window but it is giving me javascript alert to click either "Leave" or "Stay".

I tried `$browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")` code, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Watir has a built-in [`Alert`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Alert) class.  You could try `browser.alert.ok`

Answer (score 0):

execute this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: I ran it using this code "$browser.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = null:")" but it is throwing this error "unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Having trouble getting a quote? 

We noticed you're leaving the page. If you're having trouble getting a quote, call us on 6221 2111, Mondays - Fridays. 8am - 8pm and we'll get you sorted.

If you have an account with us, we will save your quote and it will be available in your Policy Manager.}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2,platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86)"

Comment: The last symbol is ';'